# iPhone UIView set resisting/position struts/springs programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have an interface which uses elements from both an .xib and programmatically added views. I"m trying to rotate the views. The .xib elements stay in position if I assign left and bottom struts, but the programmatically added elements lose their position relative to the bottom of the screen.

**How can I programmatically replace the top strut for a UIView with a bottom strut?** I know that springs can be added with

```
uiview.autoresizingmask = ...;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `autoresizingMask` property also controls "struts".  It sounds like you want to do this:

```
UIViewAutoresizing mask = myView.autoresizingMask;
mask &= ~UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
mask |= UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
myView.autoresizingMask = mask;
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, I would've never figured out logic that complex on my own :)