# how can i write the code for iphone 3.5 inches screen and 4 inches screen for ios6 & ios7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I am developing an app. In the app I wrote the code for a 3.5-inches screen and 4-inches screen for ios7&ios6. I took one view controller; in this view controller I want to display two images, one for the top and another for the bottom. On the ios7 3.5-inch screen and 4 inches screen there is no problem with the display. But on the ios6 screen for 4-inches screen and 3.5 inches screen, there is a display problem. The two images are not displayed properly. I don't know how to write the same code for both the ios6 and ios7 for  4-inches& 3.5 inches screen. Please give me ideas, anyone. I am new to programming. Thanks in advance.

The below is my code.

Viewcontroller.m (3.5 inches and 4-inches screen for ios7 & ios6).

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
{
    imgLogo=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 65, 162, 57)];

    imgLogo.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo-01.png"];

    [self.view addSubview:imgLogo];

    imgBuilding=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 415, 300, 153 )];

    imgBuilding.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-02.png"];

    imgBuilding.alpha=0.4;

    [self.view addSubview:imgBuilding];
}
else
{
    imgLogo=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 70, 162, 57)];

    imgLogo.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo-01.png"];

    [self.view addSubview:imgLogo];

    imgBuilding=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 345, 320,140 )];

    imgBuilding.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-02.png"];

    imgBuilding.alpha=0.4;

    [self.view addSubview:imgBuilding];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to check whether os is IOS 7 or Earlier and depending upon that you have set your imageView.

```
    UIImageView *imgLogo;
    UIImageView *imgBuilding;
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
    {
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
        {
            imgLogo=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 65, 162, 57)];
            imgBuilding=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 415, 300, 153 )];
        }
        else
        {
            imgLogo=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 45, 162, 57)];
            imgBuilding=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 395, 300, 153 )];

        }
        imgLogo.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];

        [self.view addSubview:imgLogo];
        imgBuilding.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];

        imgBuilding.alpha=0.4;

        [self.view addSubview:imgBuilding];
    }
    else
    {
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
        {
            imgLogo=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 70, 162, 57)];
            imgBuilding=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 345, 320,140 )];
        }
        else
        {
            imgLogo=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 50, 162, 57)];
            imgBuilding=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 325, 320,140 )];
        }
        imgLogo.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];

        [self.view addSubview:imgLogo];
        imgBuilding.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];

        imgBuilding.alpha=0.4;

        [self.view addSubview:imgBuilding];
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Did you try this? Please Accept answer which will solve your problem so in future other can use it. Thanks @user2930730

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via `autoResizing` aka '**Spring and Struts**' or by utilizing the latest '**Autolayout**' feature.
Either way allows you to maintain a single xib file while the positioning and sizing of the `subViews` remains the same (*depending on the way you have set it up*)

They can be set up via xib/storyboard as well as programmatically.

---

**Springs and Struts** was the previous method but it's still available:

- **Spring** is the stretching ability of the `subView`
- **Strut** is the placement or you can say, the ***hugging*** ability. (i.e. it hugs the top bound or the bottom bound or left or right)

Links:

- [UIView autoresizingMask - Interface Builder to Code - Programmatically create struts and springs - Swift or Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468389/uiview-autoresizingmask-interface-builder-to-code-programmatically-create-st)
- [iPhone UIView set resisting/position struts/springs programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291826/iphone-uiview-set-resisting-position-struts-springs-programmatically)

---

**Autolayout** requires you to be comfortable with the concept of constraints
*It's a tad bit more effort but hey, if apple says it's better, it sure is*.

Links"

- http://matthewmorey.com/creating-uiviews-programmatically-with-auto-layout/
- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html

---

NOTE: *You can't use both together. You have to disable **Autolayout** feature on the view if you want to use **Springs & Struts***

Comment: Can you provide some more details please?